# Call a function written in JNI from java without loading a DLL

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I have a code written in C with JNI that loads a java class with CallStaticVoidMethod.
I want the java class to be able to call a specific function from the C code.
I've seen examples over the web, but all of them were loading a DLL that has nothing to do with the java class (using System.loadLibrary).
Is it possible that the java class will call a function from the original C code that loaded it?

Comment: I dont think you can. Here's a link that might help you with it- https://iwill21.wordpress.com/2012/06/29/java-native-interface/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21734539/192373. The key is `RegisterNatives()` JNI function.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do native methods you could also pass function pointers to Java and use [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) to call the function.

(I'm using this to call functions in COM object vtables on Windows, because I didn't want to write a wrapper DLL for every object. The difference is that I don't pass the function pointers in but compute them from the object address.)